# Silverstripe - how do I upload an existing tar.gz of a fully functioning SS site?

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I've changed hosts. They have softaculous and silverstripe.

After I installed this, is there an easy way to unload an existing site tarball?

Is it necessary to install silverstripe on the server, or can the tar.gz file and database cover it? Tried that, and some issues with the contact form occurred.

Comment: Can you be more specific about some issues that occurred? Ideally you would install with composer, but you should also be able to extract a tarball and DB dump and it should be OK

Comment: It is not necessary to install Silverstripe on the server using softaculous. If your tar.gz contains all of the files from the old host, and you have a copy of your database you should be able to import the database, and unzip the tar in the proper location on your new host. I think you should blow away the softaculous install, set everything up using the tar again and troubleshoot the contact form. Make sure dev mode is enabled so you can see the errors.

Comment: After much troubleshooting, the error seems to have been php7.0 was installed on the new server, not php5.6. This is a 3.x silverstripe install. SO BASIC. I hope this helps anyone transferring a site!